# How to return a cerbot process after the session is interrputed

Tags: linux

While I was waiting for the DNS txt setting, the session was broken. I want to return the process and continue the following process. How can I do?

```
root@device1:~/youtube# sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns
Another instance of Certbot is already running.
```

Here is the process info.

```
root@device1:~/youtube# ps -ef | grep certb
root      7963  7836  0 07:35 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns
root      7964  7963  0 07:35 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns
root      8571 19933  0 08:01 pts/9    00:00:00 grep --color=auto certb
```

Comment: Just kill the running process

Comment: I would suggest to use `kill -9 7963 7964` and maybe for the next time use `screen` or similar tools to keep on in case of connection problems

Comment: @djdomi got it. thanks anyway.

Comment: did I solved the problem? in case yes let me know about that i can write that as a answer that you can accept, I would be happy to it

Comment: @djdomi Yes, I just did what you recommend.  you can write the answer, thanks alot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To kill a Program and *really* force to terminate it

kill -9 PID

if you are lazy you can also use

killall -9 program_name

In your point would it be needed to kill both PID (Process Identification Descriptors

you can use

kill -9 PID PID

in case you have a instable Internet connection I suggest, that you can use a program like screen which can be detached and resumed. Even if you are lost the connection you can resume later on.